# Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier returns nil

Tags: swift4, bundle-identifier

Anybody can tell me when is the case where `Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier` will returns nil?

```
if let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier {
    UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
}
```

With the code above, there are "random cases" where `UserDefault` was not cleared so I can only assume that the `Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier` is nil thus the statement were not executed. This is needed in our app otherwise the app will crash if the "old UserDefault" be use and we received number of crash logs because of this.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find anything? I've noticed the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing. Our team decided to ignore it for now.